# Unable to install mysql-connector-python in pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

Following is the error produced when I try to install "mysql-connector-python" in pycharm. Any help would be great.

```
Non-zero exit code(1)

Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\karan.gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe'.

Collecting mysql-connector-python
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-connector-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748) - skipping

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `pip install mysql-connector` from your Terminal, as the error handler suggests. Or try to run the same command from wherever you've already tried, but without the *-python* at the end.

Comment: It says “pip is not recognised as internal or external command”. I need to switch to the directory where python is installed?

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: I am on Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Try running 'python -m pip install -U pip setuptools' , if that fails:
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  <- download this file, switch to the directory where you've downloaded it and run python get-pip.py, then try running the command i've given in the answer above.

Comment: ython 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install mysql-connector
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install mysql-connector
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ok it ended and produced this:

 if __name__ == "__main__":
...     main()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Comment: Try running 'py -m pip install mysql-connector', if this works I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nope :(.
` py -m pip install mysql-connector
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -m pip install mysql-connector`
Its not recognizing pip

Comment: That's just odd, since you have Python 3.6 and all Python versions above 2.7 if I'm correct are automatically shipped with Pip installed. I can only refer you to [this link for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) You should really install pip first as you'll need it further on.

Comment: Yeah even I’m wondering...should I remove everything and re install? Maybe that’ll help

Comment: Go for it, we have to end the discussion here, we're breaking community standards, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://shdhumale.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/how-to-install-mysqldb-for-python-3-6-and-mysql-5-7-12/)!
Use MySQLdb instead, i used it and it's working fine. Method is in the blog. 
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I believe this version of the connector works only with python 2.7, if you try installing it with python 2.7 version, maybe it will work.